# While Loop runs forever and does not return in binary serach

Tags: c, binary-search

Trying to implement a binary algo for a reverse array input.
When I execute for the test case - 
5 4 3 2 1  its shows me a blank screen i.e the while loop runs infinitely.Trying to debug it for along time now but could not figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int findright(int arr[], int key, int low, int high);

void main() {
  int n, i, arr[200], key;
  scanf("%d %d\n", &n, &key);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  }
  int a = findright(arr, key, 1, n - 1);
  printf("%d", a);
}

int findright(int arr[], int key, int low, int high) {

  int mid = (low + high) / 2;
  while (low <= high) {
    if (arr[mid] == key) {
      return mid;
    } else if (arr[mid] > key) {
      findright(arr, key, mid + 1, high);
    } else {
      findright(arr, key, low, mid - 1);
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to use recursion or iteration?

Comment: I'm trying to use recursion

Comment: then why do you have a while loop?

Comment: Is your intent that `findright` should be recursive? If so, it will loop forever because you never change `low/high`. The `while` should probably be an `if`. If you want iteration, you want to move `mid = (low + high) / 2` _inside_ the loop

Comment: you also have an off-by-one error in your main.  you are passing 1 as `low` and therefore will never check the 0-th element.

Comment: Design it so it stands a chance of working, then user your debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your loop `while (low <= high) { ...`, values for `low` and `high` are not altered; hence, if the loop is once entered, it will never return.

As you use recursion, you will not need the loop:

```
int findright(int arr[], int key, int low, int high) {

  if (low > high) { // anchor stopping recursion
    return -1;  // indicate that key was not found...
  }

  int mid = (low + high) / 2;
  if (arr[mid] == key) {
      return mid;
  } else if (arr[mid] > key) {
      return findright(arr, key, mid + 1, high);
  } else {
      return findright(arr, key, low, mid - 1);
  }
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/Lj7eTZ)

Note further, that - as mentioned by MFisherKDX - "you also have an off-by-one error in your main. You are passing 1 as low and therefore will never check the 0-th element".

Comment: Doesn't work for first element in array due to off by 1 error in OPs main.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. The `while` needs to be changed to an `if`.
2. The recursive calls need to have `return` before them.
3. You are calling the function with the wrong value for `low`.

---

```
int findright(int arr[], int key, int low, int high) 
{
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (arr[mid] == key)
    {
        return mid;
    }

    // Terminate recursion when the item is not found.
    if ( low == high )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (arr[mid] > key)
    {
        return findright(arr, key, mid + 1, high);
    }

    else
    {
        return findright(arr, key, low, mid - 1);
    }
}
```

The call

```
int a = findright(arr, key, 1, n - 1);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
int a = findright(arr, key, 0, n - 1);
```

---

One thing to note is that the standard library functions work with iterators such that the *end* is one past the last valid iterator. When you implement a function using indices, the analogous value will be the an index that is greater than 1 of the the highest valid index. You would call the function as:

```
int a = findright(arr, key, 0, n);
```

and implement the function slightly differently as:

```
int findright(int arr[], int key, int low, int high) 
{
    // Terminate recursion when the item is not found.
    if ( low == high )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (arr[mid] == key)
    {
        return mid;
    }

    if (arr[mid] > key)
    {
        return findright(arr, key, mid + 1, high);
    }

    else
    {
        return findright(arr, key, low, mid);
    }
}
```